# src point at folder instead of file?

Tags: html, src

Can you use `<script src="/Gamefolder/Project1"></script>` as a whole folder?

Rather than use `<script src="/Gamefolder/Project1/Character/Besse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Just asking as add specific files, each time I make a new file, to HTML are getting tiresome and making a mess of my HTML. Pretty sure I am missing two file links there, just got to wait until it asks for something from missing file, then I will know there is something missing.

Comment: No, you can't do that

Comment: I see, that a shame.